# How to use models in express framework with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to use models in express framework (NodeJS). How can I use the function AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT or the classic JOINS as a model language in express framework, I say that I am currently working with db.find, etc.

Is there a way to express these functions? Or I need to declare this in pure sql language and store it in a variable and after execute it?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question correctly but there are a ton of ORMs for nodejs one of the must popular ORM is [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)

Comment: Hello David, for example I use the following models to implement mysql with express: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-model. But I do not see how to query with AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT or JOINS into this models. I need to use explicit sql language to use this?

Comment: Oh I never used mysql-model but from the documentation it looks like your going to have to do it with raw SQL